# run time variable access in python

Tags: python, declaration

I am new to python. Here I was testing on example where varialbe `wordlist` has been used in loop.

Do I need to declare it manually before using it? or it would get declared runtime?

I even tried with manual declaration but then it remains empty.

I am following this example: http://www.sjwhitworth.com/sentiment-analysis-in-python-using-nltk/

If I directly use this:

```
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in stopwords.words('english')]
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in customstopwords]
```

it gives error:

```
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in stopwords.words('english')]
NameError: name 'wordlist' is not defined
```

I manually declared `wordlist` like this

```
wordlist = []
```

but then it remain empty in this case:

```
wordlist = []
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in stopwords.words('english')]
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in customstopwords]

print wordlist
```

What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You need to set `wordlist` before you use it. If it's not set, it gives the error you have. If you set it to an empty list, it will remain empty, because the list comprehensions don't add anything to the list

Comment: @hlt: thanks dude.  can you please tell me what should be assigned to wordlist? looking at link. Much appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how list comprehensions work in python. Say you have a list `x` like

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
```

and you would like to increment its values using list comprehension:

```
y=[element+1 for element in x]
#   ^               ^       ^
#element         element    list on which
#to be added                operations are
#in list of y               performed
```

This outputs:

```
y=[2,3,4,5]
```

In your case `x`(i.e., `wordlist`) is empty so, the `for` loop does not iterate. According to the mentioned [link](http://www.sjwhitworth.com/sentiment-analysis-in-python-using-nltk/)'s description `wordlist` should be an array of artist names.

```
wordlist = ["Justin Timberlake", "Tay Zonday", "Rebecca Black"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first list comprehension:

```
wordlist = [i for i in wordlist if not i in stopwords.words('english')]
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
tmp_lst = []
for i in wordlist:
    if i not in stopwords.words('english'):
        tmp_lst.append(i)
wordlist = tmp_lst
```

When you read it this way, it's clear that `wordlist` must be something iterable *before* you ever get to that statement.  Of course, *what* `wordslist` should be is up to you and is completely dependent on what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: thanks dear for answer. I replace with your above code but still it gives  same error at line two in your code

Comment: thanks dude, I sorted out. just filled wordlist `wordlist = getwordfeatures(getwords(tweets))`